# How can I print to screen the returned string from a json + http post in java

Tags: java, json, apache, http, nginx

I am making a json + http post in java. If the http post is successful, I should have a unique identifier string return to me from the endpoint/server. So far, my post is successful but I do not know how to print to the screen this unique identifier.

Below is the output I get when I run the program;

`HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Server: nginx/1.6.2, Date: Sat, 13 Dec 2014 09:03:41 GMT, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 24, Connection: keep-alive, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, X-Parse-Platform: G1, X-Runtime: 0.166030] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 24,Chunked: false]}}`

How do I print the return object to screen?

EDIT:

Here is my code;
    //import libraries

```
public class XXXXXXXX {


    public static void main(String[] args ) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Registration ifeanyi = new Registration();
        String endPoint = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/api/register";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(endPoint); 
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        ifeanyi.email = "xxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com";
        ifeanyi.github = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx/code2040Challenge.git";

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try {               
            StringEntity data = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(ifeanyi));
            post.setEntity(data);
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse result = httpclient.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = result.getEntity();
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println(post);
        } catch (Exception handle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            handle.printStackTrace();           
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It's showing up on my screen just fine.

Comment: Can you show us some code? All you have printed there is the response headers.

Comment: What I need is not the Post report but the unique string that I should get if my post is successful. I need to be able to see that string in order to complete the rest of my assignment. @JamesB, sure.

Comment: Since @JamesB mentioned response headers, I guess I need the response body -which would contain the info I'm looking for- to be printed to the screen as well.